# Unable to retrieve full SMTP error log PHP mailer

Tags: php, mysql, email, phpmailer

I've created simple table `log` where I insert records if mails were unable to sent.

```
mysql> describe log;
+--------+-----------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field  | Type      | Null | Key | Default             | Extra                       |
+--------+-----------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
| id_log | int(11)   | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment              |
| error  | text      | YES  |     | NULL                |                             |
| time   | timestamp | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+--------+-----------+------+-----+---------------------+-----------------------------+
```

And on my PHP side, error logging is like this:

```
  foreach ($arrayWithMails as $key => $value) {
        $mail->addAddress($value);
        if (!$mail->send())
        {
            put('message', $mail->ErrorInfo); //store in session
//            echo $mail->ErrorInfo;

        }
        else {
            /* Add email from array in session to be displayed at main page */
            put('emailAddresses', $arrayWithMails); //Store in session

        }
        $mail->ClearAllRecipients();
    }
$log->logError($_SESSION['message']);
```

It calls a method in my class which passes string as a parameter, and inserts into DB.

However, all my logs are looking like this:

```
mysql> select * from  log;
+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
| id_log | error                                                                              | time                |
+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
|      1 | SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting | 2016-10-21 15:08:30 |
|      2 | 1                                                                                  | 2016-10-21 15:12:04 |
|      3 | 1                                                                                  | 2016-10-21 15:13:42 |
|      4 | SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting | 2016-10-21 15:14:14 |
|      5 | SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting | 2016-10-21 15:17:02 |
|      6 | SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting | 2016-10-21 15:18:22 |
|      7 | SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting | 2016-10-21 15:28:02 |
|      8 | SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting | 2016-10-21 15:28:53 |
+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
```

And my SMTP debug is set to `4`. Tried with `2` as well - same results.

If f.e. I do basic echo of `$mail->ErrorInfo` I get full log, with errors, but when I want to store that full log info in DB I get only :
`SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting`
Same thing occures if I try to store that error in $_SESSION var.

Any idea how to store full log ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`ErrorInfo` includes only the error message, not a full debug log. Debug output is just that - it's dumped to stdout by default, not kept.

To capture it you need to look at the `Debugoutput` property - in recent versions of PHPMailer you can set that to a callable which you can use to collect debug output and insert that in your DB.

For example:

```
//Before sending
$debuglog = '';
$mail->Debugoutput = function($str, $level) use ($debuglog) {
    $debuglog .= $str;
};

//... after calling send()
$log->logError($mail->Errorinfo . ' ' . $debuglog);
```

Comment: hi and thanks for help. I am not actually sure how to implement your solution in my code. I've edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

This covers my answer. I am extending PHPMailer and I've included that it will throw a exceptions, so this way I get exception message properly.

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $mail->addAddress($value);
    try
    {
        if (!$mail->send()) {
            put('message', $mail->ErrorInfo); // Storing for frontend, that error exist, for detailed info - log is in DB

        }
        else {
            /* Add email from array in session to be displayed at main page */
            put('emailAddresses', $array);
        }
    } catch (phpmailerException $exc)
    {
        $debugError = $exc->errorMessage();
    }

    $mail->ClearAllRecipients();
}
$log->logError($debugError);
```

Comment: This approach doesn't get you any further because the message in the exception will be the same as in ErrorInfo.

Comment: @Synchro nop mate, I get this output for example: 
`select * from  log;
+--------+-------------------------------------+---------------------+
| id_log | error                               | time                |
+--------+-------------------------------------+---------------------+
|     77 | SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. | 2016-10-21 18:51:42 |
+--------+-------------------------------------+---------------------+
`

Comment: But that's not the transcript, which is what you asked for?

Comment: For current purposes - this is enough info :)) Thanks!